# Help with reinstalling Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I used Mercurial on my old computer without any trouble a month ago, but it broke on Friday and I needed to reinstall. Now when I try to do anything from my repository directory I get the error:

> 'hg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

When I try to do anything from the Mercurial directory it gives me the error

> abort: There is no Mercurial repository here <.hg not found>!

I've updated the `hgrc` file with my info if that makes a difference. How can I get this working?

Comment: add the location of mercurial to your PATH.

Comment: im going to sound stupid, but how do i do that?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows? Mac OS X? Some flavor of Linux?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like your "path" environment variable doesn't include mercurial executables. therefore, you can probably append something like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\" (assuming windows). you could also specify the full path to hg.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\hg.exe" followed by any arguments.

the second scenario is because you are in the mercurial directory (which includes hg.exe, so doesn't depend on path anymore). but, it is not a repository and you get the ".hg not found".

hope that helps.